# Increase Vertical Line Length in Algorithm Block

Tags: algorithm2e

I would like to increase the line length of the vertical line between the start and the end
of the block in the following example using the `algorithm2e` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered, boxed, vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\ForEach{\begin{tabular}[t]{l} condition 1\\ condition 2\end{tabular}}{
stuff
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: output1]

The output I desire is:

[image: updated]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a special case for you conditional setup, so you'll have to treat the on a one-off basis:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered, boxed, vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\ForEach{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} condition 1\\ condition 2\end{tabular}}}{
  \rule{0pt}{1.8\baselineskip}stuff
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I've `\smash`-ed the conditions, removing any vertical height/depth. Then, to supplement the possible overlay with line 2, a vertical strut (zero-width rule with height) is inserted.